# How come autoboxing doesn't work for Short(5)?

Tags: java, casting, wrapper, autoboxing

How / why is is that autoboxing works for the first example below, but not the second? What's the reasoning / logic behind this?

```
Short i = 5; // works
Short i = new Short(5) // doesn't work

Short i = new Short( (short) 5) // works again, but uses explicit cast
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html) indicates, there is no constructor in `Short` taking an int as argument. And 5 is an int.

Autoboxing is irrelevant. What would be needed for this to work is auto-narrowing.